# How to pass Array as parameter to SOAP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

Currently I'm using [Savon](http://savon.rubiii.com) to work with WebService in ruby.
It works pretty well but I have difficulty to pass parameter for
argument of SOAP array type. Following code doesn't work properly:

```
ids = [0,1,2]
client.do_get_items { |soap| soap.body = {
    'item-list' => ids
}
```

I would appreciate if you can solve my problem or propose an alternative
library for ruby&soap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just stumbled on the same problem and the temporary workaround that worked for me is as follows:

```
ids = [0,1,2]
client.do_get_items { |soap| soap.body = {
  'item-list' => {
    'item1' => 0,
    'item2' => 1,
    'item3' => 2
  }  
}
```

The names "item1", "item2" shouldn't matter at all.

I use the following helper method to convert regular arrays into SOAP mess:

```
def soap_array(array)
  returning({}) do |hash|
    array.each_with_index do |e, i|
      hash["item-#{i}"] = e
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good advice, though it may not always be enough. Some SOAP servers also ask for SOAP-ENC:Array or similar attributes. Savon support for arrays is still very limited.

Comment: Thank you! Saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I had to send array of strings as two of the request's arguments. I used Savon version 2. My final solution looks like this:

```
class JvMatching

    CLIENT_ID = 'bb_matchnig'

    extend Savon::Model

    operations :query_index

    # arg1, arg 2 - name of parameters that should be arrays of string
    def self.query_index(contents=[], constraints=[], focus='job', result_size=20)
        super(message: { arg0: CLIENT_ID, arg1: { item: contents }, arg2: { item: constraints }, arg3: focus, arg4: result_size })      
    end  

end
```

What helped me to find the right solution was downloading [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) and checking how proper requests should look like.